# Google PageSpeed suggests to remove meta charset tag

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, character-encoding

I use HTML5 meta tag for character encoding:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

When I run [pagespeed](/questions/tagged/pagespeed) test, it gives me the following suggestion:

> The following resources have a character set specified in a meta tag. Specifying a character set in a meta tag disables the lookahead downloader in IE8. To improve resource download parallelization, move the character set to the HTTP Content-Type response header.

under the **Experimental rules** menu. I know it does say that I'd better use PHP version and I do:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

But Should I completely remove the meta tag? But will not it force another issues for other browsers or devices?

Does anyone has an idea about this? Is the issue for only [ie8](/questions/tagged/ie8) or is well-known code performance practice?

Answer (score -2):

There's a blog post which from about a year ago, all credit to that, here you go. 
http://diywpblog.com/avoid-a-character-set-in-the-meta-tag/
It suggests adding a rule in the .htaccess file that sets the default character encoding as UTF-8.

```
  # pass the default character set
  AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Comment: While that is an interesting fact, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Well, atleast it does state that it is IE8 only and masses need not bother bout it ;)